# What versions of the PSP does Monster Hunter Freedom Unite work on?

Tags: monster-hunter-freedom-unite

I am a new PSP gamer and am deciding on which PSP console to buy. I am wondering which PSP version is best for me. Which consoles do Monster Hunter Freedom Unite work on? What are the basic differences between the different consoles that run Monster Hunter Freedom Unite?

Comment: Do you have reason to believe it *won't* work?

Comment: @Frank. If I'm not mistaken, the PSP got a CPU clock increase somewhere along the way, though older PSP models got it too through a system update. And just recently the New 3DS was announced whose faster CPU means some games won't be compatible to the old 3DS/2DS. It's not difficult to imagine some people would start to have doubts.

Comment: @Nolonar And yet, nowhere in here do we actually have anything approaching any reason whatsoever that would give rise to this question.  To my mind, this was asked with zero research and zero effort.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I know all PSP games work on all PSP consoles. The only exception to this are games that are only available on UMD discs. These games won't work on the PSP Go because it doesn't have a UMD drive. So the download version of Monster Hunter Freedom Unite will work on all PSP consoles. The UMD version will work on all PSP consoles except the PSP Go. The download version (only) will also work on the PS Vita.

The PSP 2000, PSP 3000, PSP E1000, PSP Go models have twice the RAM as the original PSP 1000, but this memory isn't directly usable by games. It won't make a difference in terms of features, but might improve loading times because it's used as a cache for UMD accesses. The Europe only PSP E1000 budget model doesn't support WiFi so networking features of games won't work with this model. The PSP 3000 has an improved screen, though some people complained about a noticeable interlacing-like effect with this model.

Other than that the differences between the versions is physical, with the models getting progressively smaller. The PSP Go was a major redesign in terms of layout, while the other models have minor button adjustments.